# Beyond sexaquarks?

Tags: standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, confinement, hadron-dynamics, pentaquarks

There are some candidates for tetraquarks, pentaquarks or even now sexaquarks/hexaquarks. But, I wonder, what are the highest molecular quark states taking into account QCD? Are there heptaquarks, octaquarks, nonaquarks, decaquarks...stable enough to be found in colliders or Nature?

Comment: sexaquarks.  I just can't :D

Comment: Triskaidekaquarkium? That would be an unlucky combination.

Comment: helium, lithium, beryllium, the list goes on!